# How to add checkbox or radio button inside the map method in react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to add the checkbox or radio button inside the map method. I have created question and answer app. I need to add checkbox or radio button for the answers.  Below in the card component is where the question and answer is getting printed out. How can i add the radio button in there so user can check the answer.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Fragment } from "react";
    import "./Survey.css";
    import CreateSurvey from "../modals/CreateSurvey";
    import Card from "../card/Card";
    
    const Survey = () => {
      const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
      const [surveyList, setSurveyList] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let arr = localStorage.getItem("surveyList");
        if (arr) {
          let obj = JSON.parse(arr);
          setSurveyList(obj);
        }
      }, []);
    
      const deleteSurvey = (index) => {
        let tempList = surveyList;
        tempList.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
        setSurveyList(tempList);
        window.location.reload();
      };
    
      const toggle = () => {
        setModal(!modal);
      };
    
      const updateListArray = (obj, index) => {
        let tempList = surveyList;
        tempList[index] = obj;
        localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
        setSurveyList(tempList);
        window.location.reload();
      };
    
      const saveSurvey = (surveyObj) => {
        let tempList = surveyList;
        tempList.push(surveyObj);
        localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
        setSurveyList(surveyList);
        setModal(false);
      };
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="header text-center">
            <h5>Survey</h5>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
              Create Survey
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="survey-container">
            {surveyList &&
              surveyList.map((obj, index) => (
                <Card
                  surveyObj={obj}
                  index={index}
                  deleteSurvey={deleteSurvey}
                  updateListArray={updateListArray}
                />
                 
               
              ))}
          </div>
          <CreateSurvey toggle={toggle} modal={modal} save={saveSurvey} />
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default Survey;
```

//Card.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Card.css";

const Card = ({ surveyObj, deleteSurvey, index }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    deleteSurvey(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-wrapper mr-5">
        <div className="card-top"></div>
        <div className="survey-holder">
          <span className="card-header">{surveyObj.name}</span>
          <p className="answer"> {surveyObj.answerOne}</p>
          <div className="icons">
            <i className="far fa-edit edit"></i>
            <i className="fas fa-trash-alt delete" onClick={deleteHandler}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

//Createsurvey.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const CreateSurvey = ({ modal, toggle, save }) => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [answerOne, setAnswerOne] = useState("");
  const [answerTwo, setAnswerTwo] = useState("");
  const [answerThree, setAnswerThree] = useState("");
  const [answerFour, setAnswerFour] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "question") {
      setQuestion(value);
    } else {
      setAnswerOne(value);
    }
  };

  const saveHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let surveyObj = {};
    surveyObj["name"] = question;
    surveyObj["answerOne"] = answerOne;
    surveyObj["answerTwo"] = answerTwo;
    surveyObj["answerThree"] = answerThree;
    surveyObj["answerFour"] = answerFour;
    save(surveyObj);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Create a Survey Question</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <form>
            <div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Survey Questions</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={question}
                  name="question"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <label>Survey Answers</label>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 1</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerOne}
                  name="answerOne"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 2</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerTwo}
                  name="answerTwo"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 3</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerThree}
                  name="answerThree"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 4</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerFour}
                  name="answerFour"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={saveHandler}>
            Create
          </Button>
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default CreateSurvey;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding is that you want to add multiple component in map method. You can simply do it as:

```
{surveyList &&
              surveyList.map((obj, index) => (
                <>
                <Card
                  surveyObj={obj}
                  index={index}
                  deleteSurvey={deleteSurvey}
                  updateListArray={updateListArray}
                />
                <input type="checkbox" name="userchoice" />
                </> 
              ))}
```

Comment: i have added the supporting js files. I want the checkbox only for answers not for the questions as well.

Comment: I think you want to know how to render multiple components inside map. Scanning your code seem like, you are using Card component to show each answer. You can add radio button inside Card component and it should work. No need to handle it in map.